# Google Cloud Billing API using Python

Tags: python, api, google-cloud-platform, google-api-python-client, google-cloud-billing

I'm trying to get billingInfo for a google cloud project using python 3.6
I have done with request to billing API but the response is not expected,
As Google's documentation for [Billing Api](https://cloud.google.com/billing/reference/rest/v1/ProjectBillingInfo) says that it returns Name, ProjectId, billingAccountName & billingEnabled.
But it only returns name and projectId even for a project which doesn't associate with a billing account.
Here's my code:

```
            projectName = form.cleaned_data['project_id']
            # Get billing Info of selected project
            auth = getauth()
            service = discovery.build('cloudbilling', 'v1', http=auth, cache_discovery=False)
            name = 'projects/' + projectName
            billing_request = service.projects().getBillingInfo(name=name,)
            billing_response = billing_request.execute()
            data = billing_response
            print(json.dumps(data))
            if data['name']:
                return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type='application/json')
            else:
                data = []
                return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type='application/json')
```

and it returns the response as :

> {"name": "projects/docker-184805/billingInfo", "projectId": "docker-184805"}

Even billing is not enabled for this project.

How can I get the proper billing info for a project on google cloud platform using API python client?

Help me, please!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code in a project with no billing enabled (no associated billing account) and I received the same response as you, with only `name` and `projectId`.
Then, I ran it in a project with enabled billing and I received the response as the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/billing/reference/rest/v1/ProjectBillingInfo) you pointed out suggests.

> But it only returns name and projectId even for a project which doesn't associate with a billing account.

Just **enable billing for your project** and you will receive the proper billing info, with `name`, `projectId`, `billingAccountName` and `billingEnabled`.